# How to find all elments where opacity is not 0

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to find all `<tr>` elements in a  table that do not have an opacity of 0.

so far I have tried:

```
 var trHeight = table.find('tr:not(:transparent)').length;
```

but that seems to change my css.

is there something like:

```
 var trHeight = table.find('tr').css('opacity !=0 ').length;
```

thank you.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/filter/ You can define a function for filtering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a filter,

```
var trHeight = table.find('tr').filter(function () {
   return $(this).css('opacity')  > 0;
}).length;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YaxEa/1/

Comment: how does this filter for items that do not have 0 opacity?

Comment: Use > 0, Ideally it should be from 0 - 1. So you could do `!= 0` or `> 0`

Comment: (with regard to your comment left on my (now-deleted) answer: you're absolutely right, a painful combination of wifi delays meant my answer didn't post until after yours, and Android autocorrect (and my own negligence in checking) meant I answered wrongly. Sigh... +1 to you, though =)